# Add options to the dropdownlist added after button click using partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which allows adding cities. Each city is added by clicking the Add button and then selecting the city from the drop down list. The first drop down list is shown initially. When clicking the addCity button it calls the Controller action AddCity and returns the partial view. The drop down list is populated from a map object where keys are the name of cities. The javascript file behind the cshtml does the work of populating the dropdown list. The first dropdownlist is populated because it is available when document is ready. After clicking the Add button, how should I make sure that the new drop down list also has the cities in its options.

Here is my main view and partial view.

MainView.cshtml

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div id="info">
        @Html.Partial("_City")
    </div>
    <button id="addCity" class="btn" data-url='Url.Action("AddCity")'> Add </button>
</form>
```

_City.cshtml

```
<div class="city-info">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu cityList"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Controller class has:

```
public ActionResult AddCity()
{
    return PartialView("_City");
}
```

The javascript file code has:

```
var cityMap = {...some data...}
// Add new city on button click
$(function () {
    $('#addCity').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $infoDiv = $('#info');
        var url = $(this).data('url');

        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $infoDiv.append(data);
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.each(cityMap, function (key, value) {
        $(".cityList").append("<li> <a tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"#\">" + key + "</a> </li>");
    });
}
```

How can I apply the same function to the newly added cityList items? I tried some jquery but I fail to find the newly added dropdownlist (cityList) element.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what "AddCity" is supposed to do, just return the template? Is the selected city in the dropdown list being added to something or are you adding a city to the dropdown list itself?

Comment: AddCity is just adding the partial view but I also want that the dropdownlist in the partial view is also populated from the cityMap keys.

Comment: But what is it doing when you call it from AJAX?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. The selected drop down values is used to generate an xml file on the client. I have that piece working fine.

Comment: I don't understand what that AJAX call does since it doesn't seem to mutate data in any way, you'll just be replacing the element with an element that you populate with the same values. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: How else do you advise to add the partial view to the main view on button click. I tried with just jquery but the problem is that I needed atleast one element of the partial view (in this case city-info). I have a scenario where this element can be deleted.

Comment: Why not handle it all client side? You already have it on the page, just toggle visibility or take it out and store it in a variable and put it back as needed. I don't see that calling that action is necessary.